# A weird IntelliJ question - Error in inline php script to a HTML page

Tags: java, php, html, sockets, intellij-idea

**Environment**
I have been trying to implement a simple HTTP server in Java via Socket Programming

So every HTML page is send using guidelines in RFC [7230](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230)

```
String response =
                    "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" + CRLF +    // Status Line : HTTP_VERSION RESPONSE_CODE RESPONSE_MESSAGE
                    "Content-Length: " + htmlData.getBytes().length + CRLF +    // HEADER
                    CRLF +    // new-line(/r/n)
                    htmlData +    // CONTENT
                    CRLF + CRLF;
```

I was trying to generate dynamic response on the webpage itself.
But code wasn't working accordingly with this Java HTTP Server

While, when I use Xaamp server with same html page, the page was displaying correctly (not like with Java server where it show the inline HTTP code) also the request was handled too

My guess is I have to set some headers inside the response string to let the browser know that there is inline php script inside the httpdata.

**Code**

```
<?php
      if(isset($_POST['_post']))
      {
          echo "<h4>Hello to the environment " .$_POST['name']. "</h4><br>";
          echo "<h4>Your personalised message is " .$_POST['msg']. "</h4><br>";
      }
?>
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['_get']))
      {
          echo "<h4>Hello to the environment " .$_GET['name']. "</h4><br>";
          echo "<h4>Your personalised message is " .$_GET['msg']. "</h4><br>";
      }
?>
```

**QUES -**

**1. Why the `echo` tag in IntelliJ are of different color**

**2. Why inline php script is visible on Java Server while it is not in Xaamp**

**Screenshots**
[image: IntelliJ Code Snap]

[image: Java Server Output]

[image: Same Code in Sublime]

[image: Output with a Xaamp Server]

**Check out detailed code here [repo](https://github.com/harshit-soora/Java-HTTP-Server)**

Bonus Question - How will be the request handled on the Webpage once you fire either a GET or POST request (given that the server doesn't generate new HTTP page which is working fine)

I will post this as a new question, link is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68324660/simple-java-http-server-parsing-a-new-dynmaic-webpage-based-upon-http-request)!

Comment: PHP is rendered into HTML on the server. That's one of the things Xaamp does.

Comment: Your Java web-server most likely does not interpret PHP. In the XAMPP-stack, Apache is the web-server which is somehow equivalent to your Java web-server. PHP then works as a module of Apache (*libapache2-mod-php*). So you need to integrate PHP into your own Java web-server somehow if you want to use it.

Comment: @Matt Could to please guide me to any RFC that can explain how to use inline PHP code with HTML